# Why is the full response body not coming?

Tags: curl

I am trying to get the response body from this HTTP Request.

I tried doing it in Python (with various HTTP libraries), but for some reason the response cuts off at line 400 of what I see in the browser. So I tried with CURL and ended up with the same issue.

`curl -b "LSCOM_TIMEZONE_ID=US/Pacific; JSESSIONID=CCFD3E1C8EA041F186C176FDFBB4728E; LSCOM_SESSION_ID=D4Xpj7FXldTHiS1CdLLhFg-3D-3D123" -H "Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5" "http://fanzone.playonline.com/lscom/searchLinkshellName.do?LINKSHELL_NAME=ex&VIEW_LINKSHELL_ID_STRING=ymwFj2pKSNZhMCBWJtXUFg-3D-3D&EQUIP_LINKSHELL_ID_STRING=ymwFj2pKSNZhMCBWJtXUFg-3D-3D&IS_NORMAL_NANE_SEARCH=true&CURRENT_PAGE=1&IS_SELECT_ALL_LANGUAGE=true"`

I tried cloning all the Headers, etc.. No dice

Anyone any idea why this is happening?

Comment: is it really cutting it off, or is it simply that there is some javascript in there which is supposed to generate the rest?

Comment: its cutting off mid HTML

<in 

So definitely not JavaScript

Comment: I just ran your commandline, and it worked fine. Although, the complete output is only 136 lines. Are you behind a proxy perhaps? Maybe the content-length missmatches the actual content?

Comment: If you construct the request manually and send it with netcat or telnet, do you get the full response?